# Um método estático pode ter o mesmo nome de uma propriedade?

Tags: javascript, método, propriedade, convenções-de-nome

Já que um método estático não vai ser um método do objeto posso ter um método estático com o mesmo nome de uma propriedade definida dentro do construtor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é de facto possível, mas não podem por razões obvias ser acedidas ao mesmo tempo.

O método definido como propriedade estática deixa de estar acessível quando a classe é instanciada. E o método definido como propriedade/método da classe só é acessível depois de instanciado.

```js
class MinhaClasse {
  constructor(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    console.log('Classe', nome);
  }

  static metodoEstatico(nome) {
    return 'Método estático de ' + nome;;
  }

  metodoEstatico() {
    return this.constructor.metodoEstatico(this.nome + '...');
  }
}

var Fulano = new MinhaClasse('Fulano');
console.log(MinhaClasse.metodoEstatico('Beltrano'));
console.log(Fulano.metodoEstatico());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, pode, não há confusão entre membros estáticos e membros de instância.

```js
class Teste {
    static teste() {
        return 1;
    }
    constructor() {
        this.teste = 2;
    }
}

var x = new Teste();
console.log(x.teste);
console.log(Teste.teste());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/NameClashProperty.js).